# Reading multiple objects, in a single object, with in an array, with unique keys. into FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, object

I am trying to display this data in a FlatList.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "-N1gqvHXUi2LLGdtIumv": Object {
      "Message": "Aeaaeaea",
      "Message_CreatedAt": 1652167522975,
      "Message_by_Email": "vvvv@test.com",
      "Message_by_ID": "DgGfooQIMQQ1rs5xlmmSKCSTrKA2",
    },
    "-N1hB3A_Q7-K75UbvPSM": Object {
      "Message": "Yyoo",
      "Message_CreatedAt": 1652173063182,
      "Message_by_Email": "vvvjugu@test.com",
      "Message_by_ID": "DgGfooQIMQQ1rs5xlmmSKCSTrKA2",
    },
  },
]
```

My data looks like this, its multiple objects in a single object within an array, and each object has multiple unique Ids how can I read the data.

My FlatList code

```
 <FlatList data={data} renderItem={(Item) => <Text>{Item.item. Message}</Text>}
```

Here the problem is, FlatList is considering the main object and not the children, how can I access and render the children in a Flatlist and how can I access the unique Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can loop over, every single element, and then. de-structure it and combine the key with the body.

```
  const data = Onsnapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        const childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log({ childKey, ...childData });}
```

then you can you this data in FlatList

Answer (score 1):

You can access the keys of an object (your ids) obj using `Object.keys(obj)`. This returns an array of all the keys included in the given object, eg:

```
Object.keys(obj).map(key => console.log(key, obj[key])
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

You can also take a closer look at the `Object.entries()` and `Object.values()` functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I access the message object in a FlatList.

Comment: You need to prepare the data to contain the needed information, you can do something like `const displayData = Object.keys(data).map(id => ({id, ...data[key]}))` (that's why I mentioned this function), and then you just pass the `displayData` to FlatList as the `data` parameter.

Comment: FlatList takes array as an input, not multiple elements in an object. when i pass the solution you provided, FlatList takes the main object as a single element instead of its children. how can i access the children or the `Message` object. How can I decode the json from `[{{},{}}]` to `[{},{}]`. So that it can be used in FlatList.